# Polymer style google-map

Tags: google-maps, polymer, polymer-1.0

How can styles be applied to the Polymer 1 google-map tag?

The documentation suggests that an [object of styles](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/google-map) can be passed in via a 'styles' property on the tag.

However, when using something like [this](https://snazzymaps.com/style/134/light-dream) which previously worked without issue, the style is not being loaded in.

I've tried replacing the code from snazzymaps with an object (as opposed to an array), but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should work. Are you sure you are passing your styles object in correctly?

This gives you a styled map:

```
<google-map latitude="37.779" longitude="-122.3892" 
  min-zoom="9" max-zoom="11" language="en"
styles='[{"featureType":"landscape","stylers":[{"hue":"#FFBB00"},{"saturation":43.400000000000006},{"lightness":37.599999999999994},{"gamma":1}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","stylers":[{"hue":"#FFC200"},{"saturation":-61.8},{"lightness":45.599999999999994},{"gamma":1}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","stylers":[{"hue":"#FF0300"},{"saturation":-100},{"lightness":51.19999999999999},{"gamma":1}]},{"featureType":"road.local","stylers":[{"hue":"#FF0300"},{"saturation":-100},{"lightness":52},{"gamma":1}]},{"featureType":"water","stylers":[{"hue":"#0078FF"},{"saturation":-13.200000000000003},{"lightness":2.4000000000000057},{"gamma":1}]},{"featureType":"poi","stylers":[{"hue":"#00FF6A"},{"saturation":-1.0989010989011234},{"lightness":11.200000000000017},{"gamma":1}]}]'>
</google-map>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using single quotes for the `styles` property? I.e. `styles=''` rather than `styles=""`

That's what worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find any answers on how to pass this object inside the value of the `style` tag, but I was able to apply the styles by reading the comments in the file" google-map.html":

```
<script>

var map = document.querySelector('google-map');

map.styles = [

    {

        stylers: [

            {saturation: -100}

        ]

    },

    {

        featureType: 'water',

        stylers: [

            {color: '#1d5068'}

        ]

    }

];
```

Comment: I am trying your approach because I need to assign the styles from script, but it's not working for me so far. Any hints?

Comment: @Fausto R., could you create a jsfiddle with your code and share it here?

Comment: Sorry @DianCarlos for the delay, I missed your question. I cannot find now what I did wrong before, but I finally used a different approach within the ma-ready event function, I will post  the code as an answer below, just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on my previous comment / answer to Dian Carlos, here is code I finally used

Assuming that `styledMapDef` holds the map styles definitions object

```
var styledMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styledMapDef, {name: 'Styled'});
this.map.setOptions( {"mapTypeControl":"true","mapTypeControlOptions":{"position":"3", "mapTypeIds": ["roadmap", "satellite", "hybrid", "terrain", "styled"]}, "scaleControl": "true"} );
this.map.mapTypes.set('styled', styledMapType);
this.map.setMapTypeId('styled');
```